# swift build error i change an array of bytes to all but the first few bytes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to remove the first n bytes of an array, but get build error if I use dropFirst or removeFirst.
Ultimately, I want cumulative_receive_bytes to have all the bytes after the first \n in cumulative_receive_bytes.

```
var cumulative_receive_bytes = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)  
. . .  
var latest_hub_bytes = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)  
. . .
cumulative_receive_bytes += latest_hub_bytes
let hub_string = String(bytes: cumulative_receive_bytes, encoding: .ascii)
let hub_lines = hub_string!.split( whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
let message_from_hub = hub_lines[ 0 ]

cumulative_receive_bytes = cumulative_receive_bytes.removeFirst( message_from_hub.count + 1 )  
... ERROR IS:  Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[UInt8]'   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

cumulative_receive_bytes = cumulative_receive_bytes.dropFirst( message_from_hub.count + 1 )  
... ERROR IS:  Cannot assign value of type 'Array<UInt8>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<UInt8>') to type '[UInt8]'  <<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 1):

`removeFirst` is a mutating function - it mutates the array directly. It doesn't return the modified array.  This is why you get the error that you can't assign a function (type `()`) to your array.

You can just say

```
cumulative_receive_bytes.removeFirst( message_from_hub.count + 1 )
```

In the second case, `dropFirst` returns an `ArraySlice` - You need to use that to create a new array

```
cumulative_receive_bytes = Array(cumulative_receive_bytes.dropFirst( message_from_hub.count + 1 ))
```

A note on style, in Swift you should use camelCase for variables rather than _ -  `cumulativeReceiveBytes` not `cumulative_receive_bytes`

Comment: Mmmm -- agreed it is the correct style and easiest to type.  However, I made a career decision decades ago to stick as closely as possible to English syntax and grammar throughout code and comments, since the readability elements of the English language is a debugged "system" -- mostly -- and I find underscores easier to read throughout huge amounts of code than all words jammed together.  But I will consider camelCase.  Thanks.

Comment: If it's just your code it probably doesn't matter, but if you are working with other Swift programmers then it is good to stick to the idiomatic style of the language in which you are working.